# Can browse the URL in IE but unable to ping

Tags: c#

```
public static string GetAccessErrorString(string uri)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I am just trying to check the accesibility of a website in above code. I get below error when GetResponse method is invoked.

> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>     at WebStuff.WebsiteReachable.GetAccessErrorString(String uri, WebProxy proxy) 
>   in WebsiteReachable.cs:line 22
>
> *Error : The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.microsoft.com'*

I added this in host file and tried but it did not work too.

Actually I am able to browse the site in IE. When I give ping www.microsoft.com I get below message

> *Ping request could not find host microsoft.com. Please check the name and try 
>   again. *

Could you please help me figuring out the issue?.. If you could point out different possibilities that will be great.

Comment: Have you tried using the full URI "http://www.microsoft.com"? And I believe MS have blocked ping to their servers so that wouldn't work regardless.

Comment: You are right. When I tried pinging microsoft.com I don't get response but I get response when I run the code in my local machine. I face this issue in the VM.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably running this code behind a [proxy server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy.aspx) which needs authentication and Internet Explorer is configured to use this proxy while your code isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on to [Darin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460043/can-browse-the-url-in-ie-but-unable-to-ping/3460076#3460076). You can use the [Proxy property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy.aspx) to set the proxy server if proxy server is the issue.

By default your code should use the proxy settings of your Internet Explorer.